# Semantic implications of multiple <dd> tags

Tags: html, semantic-markup

When using [`<dl>` lists](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) to associate keys to values, is there a semantic difference between these 2 samples? Which one provides better semantics? What do multiple `<dd>` tags imply in this context?

**Sample 1**: Multiple `<dd>` items.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Authors</dt>
    <dd>John Lennon</dd>
    <dd>Paul McCartney</dd>
    <dt>Genres</dt>
    <dd>Pop</dd>
    <dd>Rock</dd>
</dl>
```

[Fangs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fangs-screen-reader-emulator/) output:

> *Definition list of two items* Authors *equals* John Lennon *equals* Paul McCartney Genres *equals* Pop *equals* Rock *List end*

**Sample 2**: Single `<dd>` contains `<ul>`

```
<dl>
    <dt>Authors</dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li>John Lennon</li>
            <li>Paul McCartney</li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
    <dt>Genres</dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li>Pop</li>
            <li>Rock</li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

[Fangs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fangs-screen-reader-emulator/) output:

> *Definition list of two items* Authors *equals List of two items bullet* John Lennon *bullet* Paul McCartney *List end* Genres *equals List of two items bullet* Pop *bullet* Rock *List end List end*

Comment: The question sees to revolve around the vague concept of "semantic" difference, and it is a topic for discussion and debate, where answers seem to be opinion-based. If the question is really "how will screen readers render the constructs?", it should be reformulated to reflect this and should be addressed on the basis of actual screen readers and user experience, rather than simplistic emulators.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela, do you have any real evidence that Fangs is more simplistic than real screen readers? I think that, by their nature, such tools are prone to oversimplification. Web pages don't easily translate to the sort of linear output a screen reader has to generate (and an emulator that outputs linear text is fundamentally similar to a screen reader, in that it's facing the same basic issue of forcing linearity).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The document that you link to contains the following example:

> In the following example, one entry ("Authors") is linked to two values ("John" and "Luke").
>
> ```
> <dl>
>  <dt> Authors
>  <dd> John
>  <dd> Luke
>  <dt> Editor
>  <dd> Frank
> </dl>
> ```

In other words, the two `<dd>` elements following a single `<dt>` element are both associated to that same `<dt>` element.

There doesn't appear to be much of a difference in terms of semantics, then, between having multiple successive `<dd>` elements, and having a single `<dd>` that in turn contains a `<ul>`. If it's important to distinguish "a list" (a `<ul>` in a single `<dd>`) from "a group of values" (multiple `<dd>`s in sequence), then I would decide based on that. If that's not important, then given a choice I would pick multiple `<dd>`s in sequence, because it is simpler.

Answer (score 11):

The relevant part of the [`dl` definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) is:

> The values within a group are alternatives; multiple paragraphs forming part of the same value must all be given within the same dd element.

I think a clear example would be a `dl` describing homonyms, e.g. "[bank](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bank)":

```
<dl>
  <dt><dfn>bank</dfn></dt>
  <dd>An institution where one can place and borrow money and take care of financial affairs.</dd>
  <dd>An edge of river, lake, or other watercourse.</dd>
  <dd>A row or panel of items stored or grouped together.</dd>
</dl>
```

↑ Here the term "bank" (`dt`) has three meanings (`dd`). Using one `dd` with a `ul` wouldn’t hold the same semantics:

```
<dl>
  <dt><dfn>bank</dfn></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>An institution where one can place and borrow money and take care of financial affairs.</li>
      <li>An edge of river, lake, or other watercourse.</li>
      <li>A row or panel of items stored or grouped together.</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

↑ Here the term "bank" would have only one meaning (and this meaning consists of or is described by a `ul`).

Coming back to your author example, you’d typically want to use the first variant (as [described by BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17705993/1591669)), because each author really is a "value" (`dd`) in the group of authors.

However, in the end it depends on your content and, more importantly, on your understanding of that content.