# Most suitable HTML5 element for this business statement

Tags: html, semantic-markup

A strange question, but I'm struggling over semantics vs accessibility vs appearance.  Please note this question isn't related to CSS, but the underlying HTML5 code.  Usually I wouldn't post this type of question, but this has really erupted into a debate.

I have a business statement on a website that defines why my organisation is the best (actually a sample statement...):

[image: Power statement]

TL;DR What is the best HTML5 element used to display this, from a semantics/accessibility perspective?

Our initial guess was that a simple list would suffice:

```
<ul>
    <li>Footballs:</li>
    <li>Rounder</li>
    <li>Better</li>
    <li>Stronger</li>
</ul>
```

But then the argument is that sentence structure was more important, so perhaps:

```
<div>
    <span>Footballs:</span>
    <span>Rounder,</span>
    <span>Better,</span>
    <span>Stronger</span>
</div>
```

However, this approach then renders in the commas, which is unsightly.  However, the counter-argument in my mind says commas *should* be there for screen readers...

We've even considered the DataList, but it doesn't feel *quite right*...

```
<dl>
    <dt>Footballs:</dt>
    <dd>
        <span>Rounder</span>
        <span>Better</span>
        <span>Stronger</span>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Is there a specific HTML5 element that covers this type of statement?

Comment: If you're in the States, please squint and assume the first word says **Soccer Balls:** (!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of something (in this case, the benefits), and HTML offers four ways to convey this. You cover three ways, and the fourth is using `ol`, but this is only appropriate if the order is relevant, which doesn’t seem to be the case here, so we can ignore it.

#### Natural language

Just a sentence with punctuation:

```html
<p>Footballs: rounder, better, stronger.</p>
```

You can add `span` element for styling purposes. And you could even visually hide the commas, but there is no need to go this way, simply use one of the markup alternatives instead.

#### Markup: `ul`

Having "Footballs" as part of the list doesn’t make sense. This "label" should be outside of the list.

```html
<p>Footballs:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Rounder</li>
  <li>Better</li>
  <li>Stronger</li>
</ul>
```

#### Markup: `dl`

The three benefits should either be a `ul` in one `dd`, or each one should be its own `dd`. [There is a semantic difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722440/1591669), but it’s not a clear decision in this example case.

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Footballs</dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
      <li>Rounder</li>
      <li>Better</li>
      <li>Stronger</li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Footballs</dt>
  <dd>Rounder</dd>
  <dd>Better</dd>
  <dd>Stronger</dd>
</dl>
```

#### Which one to choose?

If you are fine with having and displaying the punctuation, go with the natural language solution.

If there should be no punctuation, go with the `ul`. It’s less complex than `dl`, and as you don’t have additional name-value groups, `dl` isn’t really "worth" it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with a list then write:

```
Footballs:
<ul>
  <li>Rounder</li>
  <li>Better</li>
  <li>Stronger</li>
</ul>
```

Because `Footballs` is not part of the list footbals are. You my want to add `Footballs` into some `h` tags.

The elements of second one have no semantic meaning and would be as if you would write:

```
Footballs: Rounder, Better, Stronger
```

So it is correct, if you think commas are required.

The third one would be as if you write:

```
Footballs: Rounder Better Stronger
```

So if you think it is not understandable that way and commas would be needed, then you cannot go with this approach.

I would go with the `ul` `li` version, for the business statment because I see `dl` more in a dictionary like context.